# Passbook Update Notification Message

Tags: ios, passbook, passkit, wallet

I have a small problem with the notification message shown on the device when the pass is updated. I want the message to be what I set in the `"changeMessage"` in one of the [Pass Structure Dictionary Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/LowerLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012026-CH3-SW1). Instead what is displayed is what I am assuming to be the default change message which is "Coupon changed". I have `"changeMessage"` key in the `"backFields"` key. I have set the value of that key to some text of my own (which does not include `"%@"` as said in the description of key [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/FieldDictionary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012026-CH4-SW1)).

Due to the requirements I am working on, I cannot use `"%@"` there, as it will just replace it with the whole value against the `"value"` key. So any way to accomplish this yet still ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless `%@` is present in the message, you will only ever see the generic message *"Coupon Changed"* that you have described.

If you do not want the field value to show then you can include the message you want then pad with spaces before ending in `%@`. The spaces will ensure that the value is not shown on the lock screen and should help achieve your goal.